# If a table border's right side is not visible, where should investigate?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Can you give me a tip on what to investigate or where to look at first if a table element in a div has its border's right side is not visible?

Comment: Write some code and make it easy to investigate for us. :)

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser debugger (firebug, opera dragonfly, ...) and rightclick the TD, do 'inspect element'. Check the (computed) style.

Answer (score 0):

My first test would be to test in several different web browsers and/or versions of those.

Answer (score 0):

The border will disappear if the `<div>` is set to `overflow:hidden;` your table is set to `width:100%;`

Try adding:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

...to the table element.